# SpringBatch failng after all steps,data not inserted to DB. Attempt to update step execution id=2 with wrong version (1),where current version is 2

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-batch, batch-processing

```
12:03:25.261 [http-nio-8082-exec-8] ERROR org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep - Encountered an error executing step processStep1 in job assignJob
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.checkTransactionNeededForUpdateOperation(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:398) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.3.Final.jar:5.4.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.checkTransactionNeededForUpdateOperation(SessionImpl.java:3617) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.3.Final.jar:5.4.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1473) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.3.Final.jar:5.4.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1469) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.3.Final.jar:5.4.3.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.flush(SessionFactoryUtils.java:147) ~[spring-orm-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionSynchronization.beforeCommit(SpringSessionSynchronization.java:95) ~[spring-orm-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.triggerBeforeCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:96) ~[spring-tx-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerBeforeCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:922) ~[spring-tx-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730) ~[spring-tx-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:714) ~[spring-tx-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor80.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
12:03:25.276 [http-nio-8082-exec-8] ERROR org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep - Encountered an error saving batch meta data for step processStep1 in job assignJob. This job is now in an unknown state and should not be restarted.
org.springframework.dao.OptimisticLockingFailureException: Attempt to update step execution id=2 with wrong version (1), where current version is 2
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapStepExecutionDao.updateStepExecution(MapStepExecutionDao.java:106) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.update(SimpleJobRepository.java:196) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295) ~[spring-tx-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy130.update(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy130.update(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:275) [spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148) [spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:410) [spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:136) [spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:319) [spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:147) [spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) [spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:140) [spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessor
```

Comment: Could you please provide additional info. What do you try to achieve? The relevant to your problem piece of code.

Comment: After Writer part is done, Its failing. In logger: IN WRITER::: SpringBatch service Exits into write Method. In the qqwrite method I am trying to save data in database(postgres). session.save is working and returning the id. But its not commiting in database. Tried session.flush, thats giving exception.

Comment: Writer class:
@Override
 public void write(List<? extends String> items) throws Exception {
  logger.info("SpringBatch service Enters into write Method");
  if(items!=null && !items.isEmpty())
  service.saveData(items.get(0).toString());
  logger.info("SpringBatch service Exits into write Method");
 }

Comment: Service class:
@Transactional(transactionManager = "transactionManager")
 public void saveData(String path) {
  
  Bulkdata bulk = new Bulkdata();
  bulk.setAckDt(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
  bulk.setZipPath(path);
  bulk.setCreatedTmstmp(new Date());
  bulk.setLastUpdatedTmstmp(new Date());
  System.out.println("Before calling bulk table::::  "+ bulk);
  BigInteger id = dao.saveBulkData(bulk);
  System.out.println("After saving in bulk table.. ID::  "+id);
 }

Comment: DaoImpl class:
public BigInteger saveBulkData(BulkData bulk) {
  Session session = null;
  BigInteger id = null;
  try {
   session = getSession();
   id = (BigInteger) session.save(bulk);
  } catch (Exception e) {
   LOGGER.error("Exception in saveBulkData()", e);
  } finally {
   if (session != null) {
    //session.flush();
   }
  }
  return id;
 }